# Classic implicit differentiation problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I got this classic implicit differentiation problem $ y = x^x $

I've tried to tackle it by transforming $x^x$ to the equivalent form of $e^{(\ln x)x}$:

$ y = x^x $

$y = (e^{\ln x})^x$

$y = e^{(\ln x)x}$

and then proceeded to differentiate it in the following way:

$$y'=e^{(\ln x)x} \cdot \ln x  \cdot \frac{1}{x}$$

Now, from this [video](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-calculus/taking-derivatives/implicit_differentiation/v/calculus--derivative-of-x--x-x) I have learned that this is not a correct way to solve this problem. Unfortunately, I still don't see any problems with my approach. Would anyone care to explain me where have I made a mistake?

Comment: It is incorrect to use capital $X$ and lower-case $x$ interchangeably.

Comment: And this isn't implicit differentiation (well, if it is, it is in a very trivial sense).

Comment: You differentiated $x\ln x$ wrong, and is instead $\ln x + 1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$y=x^x=e^{x\ln x}\\
\implies \dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=x^x\left(\ln x+1\right)$$
By the **chain rule and the product rule**, which is where you went wrong.

Comment: Is it not $x^{x}\left(\ln x + 1\right)$

Comment: @Chinny84 Thanks - that was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

The last two multiplication terms in your expression for $y'$ are wrong.

We calculate (I use $\log$ notation instead of $\ln$):

$(e^{x\log x})'=e^{x\log x}\cdot (x\log x)'=e^{x\log x}\cdot(1\cdot\log x+x\cdot\frac{1}{x})=e^{x\log x}\cdot(\log x+1)$.

In the third equality I used the product differentiation rule $(uv)'=u'v+vu'$